# Show that $\dfrac{k}{2^{2k-2}}=(\prod_{j=1}^k \sin \frac{\pi j}{2k})^2$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: trigonometry, proof-explanation, gamma-function

I want to prove $\Gamma(\frac1m) \dots \Gamma(\frac{m-1}{m})=(2 \pi)^{m-1} m^{-\frac12}$.

My attempts:

For $m=2l+1$, I used the reflection formula $\Gamma(\frac{k}{m}) \Gamma(1-\frac{k}{m})=\frac{\pi}{\sin \frac{\pi k}{m}}$ and then replaced $\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{x^m-1}{x-1}$ once with $m$ and once with multiplication of roots of unity which results in the requested equality to prove.

For $m=2l$ this approach fails because of appearance of $\Gamma(\frac12)$ in the middle of the list with even with many tricks I used it fails to prove the final result. Reducing it to prove this : $$\dfrac{k}{2^{2k-2}}=(\prod_{j=1}^k \sin \frac{\pi j}{2k})^2 $$ How can I approach from this line on? It is true for small numbers of $k$ but appearance of $k$ in th denominator makes by-induction-method useless.

Added : The following is from the text but I believe it works for $m$ an odd integer. Does it work for $m$ even and if so how?

[image]

Comment: multiply and divide by $\cos\dfrac{\pi}{2k}$ and watch magic unfold.

Comment: @dezdichado, not a useful approach I could make

Comment: ah, i misremembered. That approach works for the same product of cosines. The chebyshev polynomial answer is perhaps the simplest if you don't include complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that $j=k$ can be excluded from consideration as the corresponding factor is $\sin\frac{\pi k}{2k}=1$.

Second, notice that $\pm\sin\frac{\pi j}{2k}$ for $j=1,2,\dots, k-1$ are the roots of the [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) $U_{2k-1}(x)$ divided by $x$. By [Vieta theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), their product
$(-1)^{k-1}\left(\prod_{j=1}^{k-1} \sin\frac{\pi j}{2k}\right)^2$ equals the free term of $\frac1xU_{2k-1}(x)$, which is $(-1)^{k-1}2k$, divided by its leading coefficient, which is $2^{2k-1}$. That is,
$$\left(\prod_{j=1}^{k-1} \sin\frac{\pi j}{2k}\right)^2 = \frac{k}{2^{2k-2}}.$$

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't make a rigorous proof from your answer so I edited my post. Could you guide me for the added question?

Comment: @TheMagicMountain: It's a bad idea to change the question on fly as it's getting messy. I've answered the question from the title of your question. If you have another question, please ask it in a separate post.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but about the policy you indicate : I should understand the answer posted and sometimes happen that people add other answers understandable to OP to his/her knowledge. No change of question on fly.

Comment: What exactly is unclear in my answer?

Comment: 1- "free term of $\frac1xU_{2k-1}(x)$ is $(-1)^{k-1}2k$", 2- "$\pm\sin\frac{\pi j}{2k}$ are the roots" is not clear from Wiki.

Comment: 1 - look at the explicit formula for $U_{2k-1}(x)$. 2 - look at the trigonometric definition of $U_{2k-1}(\cos\theta)$ and plug in $\theta=\frac{\pi}2\pm\frac{\pi j}2k$.

Answer (score 0):

It is too long for a comment, so I post it as answer.

I will present two solutions.

**First solution**:

The approach proposed by Max Alekseyev is correct.

Let us prove

> $\dfrac{k}{2^{2k-2}}=(\prod_{j=1}^k \sin \frac{\pi j}{2k})^2$, for $k \in \mathbb{N}, k > 0$

**Let us go step by step**.

**Step 1**. Given $k \in \mathbb{N}, k > 0$, let us consider the [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the second kind $U_{2k-1}$.

We have, by definition, that
$$U_{2k-1}(\cos \theta)\sin \theta= \sin 2k \theta \tag{1}$$
and its explicit form is:
$$U_{2k-1}(x) = \sum_{t=0}^{k-1} (-1)^t \binom{{2k-1}-t}{t}~(2x)^{{2k-1}-2t} \tag{2}$$

**Step 2**. From $(2)$, we see that:

1. the degree of $U_{2k-1}$ is $2k-1$;
2. the leading coefficient of $U_{2k-1}$ is $2^{2k-1}$
3. the term of lowest degree is $(-1)^{k-1}\binom{k}{k-1}~(2x)$, that is  $(-1)^{k-1}2kx$

**Step 3**. Let us look at the roots of $U_{2k-1}$. From $(1)$,
taking $\theta = \frac{r \pi}{2k}$ where $r= 1, \dots, 2k-1$, we have

$$U_{2k-1}\left (\cos \frac{r \pi}{2k} \right )\sin\frac{r \pi}{2k}= \sin 2k \frac{r \pi}{2k} = \sin r \pi =0$$
Since for each  $r= 1, \dots, 2k-1$, $\sin\frac{r \pi}{2k}\ne 0$, we have that, for each  $r= 1, \dots, 2k-1$,
$$ U_{2k-1}\left (\cos \frac{r \pi}{2k} \right ) = 0$$
So we have that $U_{2k-1}$ has $2k-1$ distinct roots and they are $\cos \frac{r \pi}{2k}$ for $r= 1, \dots, 2k-1$.

Now, note that for each  $r= 1, \dots, 2k-1$,
$$ \cos \frac{r \pi}{2k} = \cos \left (  \frac{\pi}{2}+ \frac{(r -k) \pi}{2k} \right ) = -\sin \frac{(r -k) \pi}{2k}$$
So the roots of $ U_{2k-1}$ are $-\sin \frac{(r -k) \pi}{2k}$ for $r= 1, \dots, 2k-1$. In other words (taking $s = r-k$), the roots of $ U_{2k-1}$ are $-\sin \frac{s \pi}{2k}$ for $s= -(k-1), \dots, k-1$.

It means that the roots of $ U_{2k-1}$ are $0$ and $\pm \sin \frac{s \pi}{2k}$ for $s= 1, \dots, k-1$.

**Step 4**. Since the term of lowest degree in  $ U_{2k-1}$ is  $(-1)^{k-1}2kx$ (or, equivalently, $0$ is a simples root of $ U_{2k-1}$), we can divide $ U_{2k-1}$ by $x$. Let $P$ be the polynomial obtained by such division. It is immediate that

1. $P$ has degree $2k-2$;
2. the roots of $P$ are $\pm \sin \frac{s \pi}{2k}$ for $s= 1, \dots, k-1$;
3. the leading coefficient of $P$ is $2^{2k-1}$
4. the term of lowest degree is $(-1)^{k-1}2k$

It follows immediately that
$$(-1)^{k-1}\left (\prod_{s=1}^{k-1} \sin \frac{s\pi }{2k} \right)\left (\prod_{s=1}^{k-1} \sin \frac{s\pi }{2k} \right)=(-1)^{(2k-2)} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}2k}{2^{2k-1}}$$
that is
$$\left (\prod_{s=1}^{k-1} \sin \frac{s\pi }{2k} \right)^2=\frac{k}{2^{2k-2}}$$
Since $\sin \frac{k\pi }{2k}=  \sin \frac{\pi }{2} =1$, we can write:
$$\left (\prod_{s=1}^k \sin \frac{s\pi }{2k} \right)^2=\frac{k}{2^{2k-2}}$$

$\square$

**Second solution**: Here is another way to prove, using complex numbers, that

> $\dfrac{k}{2^{2k-2}}=(\prod_{j=1}^k \sin \frac{\pi j}{2k})^2$, for $k \in \mathbb{N}, k > 0$

**Proof**: For $k=1$, it is immediate that
$$\dfrac{k}{2^{2k-2}}= 1 = \left (\sin \frac{\pi }{2} \right)^2 =\left (\prod_{j=1}^k \sin \frac{\pi j}{2k} \right )^2$$

Now, note that for $m \in \Bbb N$, $m \geqslant 1$
$$\frac{x^{m} - 1}{x-1} = \prod_{j=1}^{m-1} \left (x-e^\frac{2j\pi i} {m} \right )$$
On the other hand,
$$\frac{x^{m} - 1}{x-1} = x^{m-1}+ x^{m-2}+ \cdots+ x +1$$
So
$$ x^{m-1}+ x^{m-2}+ \cdots+ x +1 = \prod_{j=1}^{m-1} \left (x-e^\frac{2j\pi i} {m} \right )$$
Making $x=1$, we get
$$ m = \prod_{j=1}^{m-1} \left (1-e^\frac{2j\pi i} {m} \right )$$
So, for any $k \in \Bbb N$, $k \geqslant 2$, we have (making $m=2k$),
$$ 2k = \prod_{j=1}^{2k-1} \left (1-e^\frac{j\pi i} {k} \right )$$
Now, note that, for all  $j \in \{1, \dots ,k-1\}$, $1-e^\frac{j\pi i} {k}$ is the conjugate of  $1-e^\frac{(2k-j)\pi i} {k}$. So we have
\begin{align*} 2k &= \prod_{j=1}^{2k-1} \left (1-e^\frac{j\pi i} {k} \right )= \\
&= \left [\prod_{j=1}^{k-1} \left (1-e^\frac{j\pi i} {k} \right ) \right ] \left (1-e^\frac{k\pi i} {k} \right ) \left [\prod_{j=k+1}^{2k-1} \left (1-e^\frac{j\pi i} {k} \right ) \right ] = \\
&= 2 \left [\prod_{j=1}^{k-1} \left (1-e^\frac{j\pi i} {k} \right ) \right ] \left [\prod_{j=k-1}^{1} \left (1-e^\frac{(2k-j)\pi i} {k} \right ) \right ] = \\
&= 2 \prod_{j=1}^{k-1} \left |1-e^\frac{j\pi i} {k} \right |^2 =\\
&= 2 \prod_{j=1}^{k-1} \left[ \left (1- \cos \frac{j\pi } {k} \right )^2 + \left (\sin \frac{j\pi } {k} \right )^2     \right] =\\
&= 2 \prod_{j=1}^{k-1} \left[ 2 \left (1- \cos \frac{j\pi } {k} \right )     \right] =\\
&= 2^k \prod_{j=1}^{k-1}  \left (1- \cos \frac{j\pi } {k} \right ) = \\
&=  2^k \prod_{j=1}^{k-1}  \left[ 2  \left (\sin \frac{j\pi } {2k}    \right )^2 \right] =\\
&=  2^{2k-1} \prod_{j=1}^{k-1}    \left (\sin \frac{j\pi } {2k}    \right )^2 
\end{align*}
note that we used the fact that $1 -\cos \theta = 2 \left(\sin \frac{\theta}{2} \right)^2$.

So, we have
$$ \frac{k}{2^{2k-2}}=\left (\prod_{j=1}^{k-1} \sin \frac{j\pi }{2k} \right )^2 $$
Since $ \sin \frac{k\pi }{2k}  = \sin \frac{\pi }{2}=1$, we can write
$$ \frac{k}{2^{2k-2}}=\left (\prod_{j=1}^{k} \sin \frac{j\pi }{2k} \right )^2 $$